# How to read XML file into a data table type object?

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I am trying to figure out how to read in a variety of XML files into an HTTP Servlet.  The XML files all represent a data table.  What is the best way to do this?  I'm trying to avoid being locked into a certain numbers of columns or knowing the names of the columns.

I'm not sure the best way to store the data either, I'm not very familar with what data objects are available in java.  I was thinking an multidimensional array or a list of lists.

Thank you for any advice

The XML files could look like this, from w3schools:

```
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

or this:

```
<fruits>
  <fruit>
    <name>orange</name>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <name>grapes</name>
  </fruit>
  <fruit>
    <name>bananas</name>
  </fruit>
</fruits>
```

I ended up using JDOM and creating a list of lists of strings to store the data.  The code is below, any advice/feedback is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost/test/test.xml");     
    InputStream stream = url.openStream();

    Document document = null;         

    try {
        document = builder.build(stream);
    } 
    catch (JDOMException e) {
    }

    // Get Root Element and name
    Element root = document.getRootElement();
    String rootName = root.getName();

    // Get Second Level Elements, the rows of the data table
    List<Element> items = root.getChildren(); 

    // Get column names, using the first element
    List<Element> firstItem = items.get(0).getChildren();
    ArrayList<String> colNames =  new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Element col : firstItem){
        colNames.add(col.getName());
    }
    dataList.add(colNames);

    // Get data
    for (Element item : items) {
        ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element col : item.getChildren()) {
            row.add(col.getText());
        }
        dataList.add(row);
    }
```

Comment: Use an XML schema and JAXB.

Comment: Use an XML schema?  But I don't want to write a separate method for each schema (number of columns).

Comment: A schema works by specifying the structure of an XML document; you should be able to specify a structure with a variable number of columns.

Comment: You mean your code should be able to read different XML files based on different DTD's or structures and you want to create the table and insert data on fly according to the given XML file?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I'm looking for one method that can create a data table in java from an xml file.  I'll add example xml files to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are obviously many approaches...

My favorite open source Java library for reading XML is [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/).

My favorite generic structure for storing tabular data is a list of lists of Strings. Here is how I usually define them.
List> myData = new ArrayList>();

Comment: Thanks!  I added code for my proposed solution, any advice/feedback is appreciated.